# Selecting line inside polygon and copy attribute into them

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, copy

I'm using QGIS 3.6.
I've got around 300 polygons with "name" field.
I would like to select lines inside those polygons and copy what's inside of "name" field into similar field of every line that is selected. Is there any smart method to do this and save hours of work using "Select by location" and copying name by hand?

Comment: Do the lines cross polygon boundaries and if so do you want them split with each section getting the name from the polygon overlaying it?  If so look at the Intersection tool.  If not you can look at the Join Attributes by location tools.

Comment: Thank you very much for response, ill try both tools and check what will be more suitable for me :)

Comment: So the "Join attributes by location" tool made my day. Going further into work i need to made... Is there a possible way of doing a faster thing like:
- Select points in polygon
- Do a "Basic statistics for numeric fields"
- Insert a SUM value to a specified field of vector

Comment: There is a join attributes by location (summary) tool that adds some statistical values.  If you are instead doing something separate from the actual join in this question, you may want to submit that as a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works :)